# Plot error: Attempt to execute SCRIPT grid as a function:

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to use stem3 to plot some data but I keep getting the following error

Attempt to execute SCRIPT grid as a function:
C:\Users\aaelgaal\Documents\MATLAB\grid.m

Error in stem3 (line 77)
            grid(cax,'on');

Actually I don't even have a script or anything to begin with. I have three vectors-x, y, and z; and I try to execute stem3(x,y,z) from the command window. Even when I select the vectors and go up to "Plot" tab and click on the plot I want there, I still get the same error. Anyway, Matlab still plots the data regardless of the error, which I was okay with until I needed more. Now I want to use subplot to have two plots in one figure. When I try this, Matlab shows the same error, opens up a figure with space for two plots, but only shows the first one where the other one would be blank.

Comment: Your `grid.m` might be affecting MATLAB's `grid` function. Trying renaming the m-file.

Comment: You do have a script. As mentioned in the error message. `C:\Users\aaelgaal\Documents\MATLAB\grid.m`. Either delete or rename that file, as it shadows MATLAB’s own `grid` function.